# Is there a way to change the text of the "no data" message in data studio, when there is no database in a specific date range?

Tags: looker-studio

Is there a way to change the text of the "no data" message in data studio, when there is no database in a specific date range?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In fact, it would be nice to have this option. But, as it is not available for now, I made a workaround to "hide" this:

1. Change the default font color to the same of background
2. Add a "conditional formatting" for an item of your list to the condition "not blank" and set the font color to any of your preference.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

This string is hardcoded in Table standard visual of Data Studio and currently there is no option to change this string.

However, this string follows the user current locale.  So, if the user access your report in a language different than english, it will follow the user locale.

This is an example of a table with no data in portuguese:

[image: no data in portuguese]

Notice it displays "*Não há dados*" instead of "*No data*".

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is a way to change this view in the table. You can choose how it looks when there is no data from the [Missing Data field in the Style tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYobR.png)

PS: It wasn't there when you asked, and it may have just been added. I don't know :)

Comment: ***NOTE***: The **[Missing Data](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9081354)** feature affects displaying available data and is related to NULL values; the "**No Data**" message is currently displayed when there is no data (and currently the message only changes based on the language, and there is no way to set a custom message, as noted in the answers)